# Grayscale in internal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internal

I want to set grayscale to my `div`'s background.

```
<div id="main">  
   <div id="internal">
     <span>Text in yellow color</span>   
   </div> 
</div>
```

I set `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)` in `#main`. I don't know how to turn off grayscale in internal `div` for set text in `span` to some color.
I tried to set `grayscale(0%)`, and set `z-index` but it didn't work.
Is it possible to do something like that?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blend mode which applies to background.

```css
#internal{
 background-color: gray;
 background-blend-mode: luminosity;
}

#internal > span{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">  
   <div id="internal">
     <span>Text in yellow color</span>   
   </div> 
</div>
```